# How to add a word before the last word in list?

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to this programming language

I wanted to add the word `'and'` before the last item in my list.

For example:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
```

If I print it the output must be like:

```
1,2,3 and 4
```

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: You can do `myList = '1,2,3 and 4'`... However, what do you mean by "If I print it the output"? Output of what???

Comment: take a look at `join()`, `list slicing` and `string concatenation`.

Comment: You want to add a word for printing purposes, or insert into the list in itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way, but I have to convert the int's to strings to use `join`:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
smyList = [str(n) for n in myList[:-1]]   
print(",".join(smyList), 'and', myList[-1])
```

gives:

```
1,2,3 and 4
```

The `-1` index to the list gives the last (rightmost) element.

Comment: So does `print('1,2,3 and 4')`.

Comment: @goodvibration: I don't think that hard-coding the values is what the question is looking for, but if you think it is a good answer then why not submit that yourself?

Comment: Your print statement spits this out `'1,2,3', 'and', 4`. Instead using `print(",".join(smyList)+' and '+str(myList[-1]))` might help

Comment: @Usernamenotfound: That's just creating the string object yourself instead of letting `print()` do it.  It would work, but I can't see any advantage.

Comment: your print statements prints three different strings instead of 1. More for a aesthetic print statement

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but this is how I would tackle it.

define a formatter function as follows:

```
def format_list(mylist)
    str = ''
    for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
        str.append(str(mylist[i-1]) + ', ')

    str.append('and ' + str(mylist[-1]))

    return str
```

then call it like this

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> format_list(x)
1, 2, 3, and 4
```

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood the question. I'm going to have to rewrite this completely. Standby...

Comment: Sorry @Zinki I misunderstood the question at first. I just rewrote my answer from scratch. Hopefully it's more useful for you now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use string formating:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
print("{} and {}".format(",".join(str(i) for i in l[:-1]), l[-1]))
#'1,2,3 and 4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` (to join list elements) and `map(str,myList)` to convert all integers inside list to strings

```
','.join(map(str,myList[:-1])) + ' and ' + str(myList[-1])
#'1,2,3 and 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misleading, if you are saying "How to add a word before the last word in list?" it means you want to add 'and' string before last item in the list , while many people are giving answer using .format() method , You should specify you want 'and' for printing or in list for further use of that result :

Here is list method according to your question :

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
print(list((lambda x,y:(x+['and']+y))(myList[:-1],myList[-1:])))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'and', 4]
```